# react-router prepending POST request to URL

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, react-router, flux

Thank you! Long-time extreme googler, first SO question. I have been wracking my brain for a solution to this issue, and have yet to find a solution.

I am trying to send form data from react to an express api via a `fetch` `POST` request. I have successfully used flux actions with a store and source to `GET` api data through `fetch`, and I have successfully stored `POST` requests on the express side; but whenever I submit the form and send the `POST` request, it looks like react-router is prepending the query to the `hashHistory`.

[screencap of request handled by react-router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQEjs.png)

Here's a [GITHUB GIST](https://gist.github.com/marcusguttenplan/4dd87bee20628c8e2aa13f78b195d70b) of front-end react and back-end express. And here's a tree of the application structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── projects.js
│   ├── helpers
│   │   ├── hash.js
│   │   └── passportHelper.js
│   ├── models
│   │   └── projects.js
│   ├── router.js
│   └── views
│       ├── error.hbs
│       ├── home.hbs
│       ├── layout.hbs
│       ├── login.hbs
│       └── register.hbs
├── app.js
└── src
    ├── app
    │   ├── AppRoot.jsx
    │   ├── actions
    │   │   └── ProjectCreateActions.js
    │   ├── alt.js
    │   ├── components
    │   │   └── CreateProject.jsx
    │   ├── dispatcher
    │   │   └── AppDispatcher.js
    │   ├── sources
    │   │   └── ProjectCreateSource.js
    │   └── stores
    │       └── ProjectCreateStore.js
    └── client
        ├── css
        ├── fonts
        └── js
```

I have tried a few different solutions, including `AJAX` and `XMLHttpRequests`, but with the same issue. I've tried finding ways to `<Link>` out of react-router, but can't seem to reach the express server. Not sure if it's related to how I'm setting the state, or if it's even sharing the state with the `alt` flux stores, *or if that's how states even work or if I should be using props*, but really I am just fumbling around documentation trying to get the `POST` request out of react and into express. Any tips would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to prevent the default event from firing (form submission defaults to a `GET` request if not otherwise specified):

```
_onSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   ProjectCreateStore.listen(this._onChange)
   ProjectCreateActions.postProjects()
}
```

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! I can see the `POST` on the server now. In the current implementation, I was mistakenly using `document.getElementById('x').value` in `ProjectCreateActions.js` to hold the data -- leading to an empty request. Am I able to access state from the actions, with something like `x: this.state.x`?

Comment: If you move the `onSubmit={this._onSubmit}` to the `<Form>` component, you can pass `e.target` (i.e. the form element) to `postProjects` and `target.getElementById(...)`, though that feels too tightly coupled. I would be more inclined to move the `onSubmit` as I said, pull the necessary values off of `event.target.getElementBy...` into an object and pass that object to `postProjects(formData)`. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: That definitely makes sense. With the first method, passing the event target `e.target` into `postProjects(e.target)` and then targeting the element directly throws a reference error `target is not defined`. while trying to group all of the data in an object (I tried an array) in the `CreateProject.jsx` component, but somehow somewhere that throws a `property of null` error in `onChange()` but I can't track down where the state would be becoming null. Also tried adding `getInitialState()` to set the form values to empty lines.

Comment: Successfully passed an object into the flux action, but still sending empty requests. Should the object be passed to the store instead? While reversing my `GET` I changed the request from the store to post, but didn't change `resolve(data)`, and the post with the data is coming from the fetch in the action. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I assume you are calling `postProjects(yourObject)` and setting `body` to the stringified version of that? `body: JSON.stringify(yourObject)`

Comment: Exactly. I've created an updated [gist](https://gist.github.com/marcusguttenplan/147492ed24c0db1781cc57440637499c) with the changes. `.getDocumentById('')` also is not accepting `e.target` or `event.target`. Maybe using props and data-tags to pass the data, akin to [this](http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/facebook/react/q/stackoverflow/20377837/how-to-access-custom-attributes-from-event-object-in-react)?

Comment: I set up a bunch of `console.log`s for debugging and traced the issue to the passing of the request from the `action` to the `source`. Only the hardcoded API path from `action` is making it to the `source`, hence the empty requests. Any ideas for sending a request body with the URL? I was hoping to use `fetch: function(data)` to grab all of it from the `action`, and then `$.post(data)` to send. `console.log(data)` is definitely seeing the URL. But still, no body.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Rob!!! I removed the `source` for this flow, sent the request from the `action` and saw that HTTP code was now 302 instead of 200. That could only be an issue with the auth middleware redirecting the request, so I took an axe to the express router and am now very insecurely making POST requests!!